# Eclipse not showing suggestions in Android XML

Tags: android, eclipse

I have installed Eclipse Indigo and the auto-complete feature is working normally in the Java editor.. the problem is in the XML editor, when I press CTRL+Space, nothing of the suggestions comes out.
Why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had faced the same problem. I was trying to solve using

```
sample.xml layout file -> Right click on it -> Open With -> Android Layout Editor
```

But no luck. Then I was trying another way

1. Select Project (say *Myproject*) from *Package Explorer*
2. Right click on the *Myproject*
3. Select *Properties* from popup
4. Select *Java Build Path* from left panel
5. Select *Source* from right tab
6. Select *Myproject/gen*
7. Click on *Remove* button
8. Repeat step 6 and 7 for *Myproject/src*
9. Press on *OK* button
10. Click on *Add Folder..*
11. Add the *Myproject/gen* and *Myproject/src*
12. *OK* again *OK*

It solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Find your XML file in Package Explorer and right click on it. Select `Open With -> Android Layout Editor` (or select appropriate option from other options available in sub menu). Bingo! Auto-complete/content assist should start working.